# Check out is not working at view cart in Magento - 2.2.4?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.4

I am working on Magento - 2.2.4 community edition and on porto theme.

Go to checkout is not working.

[My Website](http://www.depoto.com/vizag/)

**Steps to check the issue :**

1. Register account
2. Add products to cart
3. Go to check out page
4. After added products to cart, Directly go to check out page.

Comment: I can see that there is jQuery error in console. You should try to fix this, it may solve your issue.

Comment: @Ramkishan, Thanks for the responce. Could you please help me to solve that ?

Comment: Can you remove the require([
    'jquery',
    'js/jquery.stellar.min'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).stellar({
            responsive: true,
            scrollProperty: 'scroll',
            parallaxElements: false,
            horizontalScrolling: false,
            horizontalOffset: 0,
            verticalOffset: 0
        });
    });
}); from http://www.depoto.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Magento_Theme/js/theme.js

Comment: This is just for testing purpose. I want to know if this is the issue or not. One more thing I think you are not using parallex design then you can remove that section from your code.

Comment: Magento 2 checkout is by default slow. In your case, its slow because of theme as it uses lots of js files which slow down the speed.